# Visual Studio Debug Intellisense Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've just updated to Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.2) - after the update, intellisense when debugging isn't working.  For example, if I hover over abc (screen shot) I get the same summary as shown in the Locals (abc count=7), however I can't expand the tooltip to show the property's of the object - as shown in the Locals.

[image]

Also when I hit a breakpoint and the scroll to another part of the file, I automatically get taken back to the breakpoint after a few seconds.

These could be settings that were turned on as part of the update, however I haven't been able to find any info on this.  I've also reset all settings however I still experience the same issues.

Update:

After some further searching I came across this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/321198/variable-datatips-dont-expand.html

Looks like an issue introduced in 15.8.1

Comment: Did you checked the checkbox for `Define DEBUG constant` in the properties in your project? Should be the second tab counted from top.

Comment: @Cataklysim, thanks for the prompt response - strangely that wasn't checked, however it didn't fix the issue

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/315973/cant-expand-variable-in-vs-2017-1581-in-debug-mode.html